# Prevent Modification of dbo objects while allowing other schemas to be modified

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I have a vendor solution that uses a sql server (2008r2) database. We are allowed to do anything we want in our own schema, but cannot modify dbo objects without vendor permission. Any customization we make is in our own schema (cust).  We have full control of this server and have always allowed sysadmin rights to any developer. Lately, I've noticed these rules have not been followed, so I want to see if I can set up permissions to stop this in the first place.

Here is what I would like to accomplish:

Tables: read/write to all, alter cust schema only, view design

Views/Sprocs/Functions: view any definition, create or alter cust schema only

I created a new user (dev) and applied the following:

```
deny alter on schema::dbo to dev
grant alter on schema::custom to dev
grant view definition to dev
```

Will this accomplish what I want, or am I missing something else?

**Solution** (thanks to AMtwo)

```
use master
go
create login dev with password = 'test', check_expiration = off, check_policy = off
grant control server to dev


use CustomerDB 
go
if not exists(select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'dev') begin
    create user dev for login dev 
    grant select, insert, update, delete, execute, alter on schema::custom to dev
    grant view definition to dev
    deny alter on schema::dbo to dev
    -- deny other schemas here
end`
```

Comment: You can also try something like [DBHistory](http://dbhistory.com) to know what changed, when and by whom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> We have full control of this server and have always allowed sysadmin
>   rights to any developer.

The `sysadmin` privilege effectively short-circuits any other permissions. If a user is a member of the `sysadmin` fixed server role, then any `DENY` permissions will be ignored.

You can work-around this by revoking `sysadmin` and instead using the `CONTROL SERVER` permission. `CONTROL SERVER` is similar to the `sysadmin` fixed server role, except that `CONTROL SERVER` will obey `DENY` permissions.

```
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO dev
EXEC sp_dropsrvrolemember 'dev', 'sysadmin'
DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO dev
```

If you want to completely undo the developers' need to have high-level access on the server (which is a pretty good idea), then you could take two approaches:

- Grant wide access to the database, then explicitly deny permissions on dbo.

  ```
  USE MyDB
  GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,EXECUTE,ALTER ON DATABASE::MyDB TO dev
  GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO dev
  DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO dev
  EXEC sp_dropsrvrolemember 'dev', 'sysadmin'
  ```
- Explicitly grant just the permissions the users require; do not grant `ALTER` permission in `dbo`.

  ```
  USE MyDB
  GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,EXECUTE,ALTER ON SCHEMA::custom TO dev
  GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO dev
  GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO dev
  EXEC sp_dropsrvrolemember 'dev', 'sysadmin'
  ```

Ultimately, you want to follow (or be close to) the [principal of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). But you also have to balance complexity and manageability.

I'd suggest you create a few test scenarios to test your permissions when running as dev, so that you can make sure the user has the right permissions. You can do this using `EXECUTE AS LOGIN`:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='SomeDeveloper';
CREATE TABLE custom.AM2 (foo BIT);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE custom.GetAM2 AS SELECT * FROM custom.AM2;
GO
DROP TABLE custom.AM2;
DROP PROCEDURE custom.GetAM2;
GO
REVERT;
```

Comment: I went with your second bullet and that worked for my requirements. However, I failed to state in the questions they need to be able to create tables/views/functions etc in the custom schema. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You'll want to include the CREATE\ALTER\DROP permissions in your GRANT (I've updated my answer to include them)

Comment: I ran this statement `GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,EXECUTE,CREATE,ALTER,DROP ON SCHEMA::custom TO dev` and received this error `Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE'`

Comment: Sorry--that's what I get for trying to respond while I was on call.  They should have permission to create tables in the custom schema with the existing permissions.

Comment: I realized I never ran the `grant control server` command. Verified this was able to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this in two parts.

**What you should do**

Honestly I don't think anyone but a DBA in charge of the instance should have `sysadmin` or even `control server`.  I've only very rarely seen situations where you need to go past the following:

- Read
- Write
- Execute
- ddl_Admin
- view definition

In this case in order to grant the permissions you want you can do the following:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','dev'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter','dev'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin','dev'
GRANT EXECUTE, VIEW DEFINITION TO dev
DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO dev
```

**What you may have to do**

I understand that sometimes you don't have an option. Politics, whatever, require `sysadmin` for everyone. Although I'll say again this is a horrible idea.  That said, you can use a DDL trigger (or policy based management) to prevent changes to dbo.  It will basically bypass security.

I have an example of a DDL trigger doing something similar [here](https://sqlstudies.com/2015/02/16/tales-of-a-dba-fed-up-with-nolock-part-1/) and a policy [here](https://sqlstudies.com/2015/02/23/tales-of-a-dba-fed-up-with-nolock-part-2/).

In both cases they were demo code where I prevented the use of `nolock`.  That said you can still probably use them as a template.  You'll need to be careful to include in your code the ability to allow your vendor permission to make the changes.  Here is an example (untested) of how it might look:

```
CREATE TRIGGER No_DBO_Changes
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE,
    CREATE_FUNCTION, ALTER_FUNCTION,
    CREATE_VIEW, ALTER_VIEW,
    CREATE_TRIGGER, ALTER_TRIGGER
AS
    IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN() != 'vendoruser'
    BEGIN
        IF EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') = 'dbo'
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
        END
    END
GO
```